# Creating a pojo for springboot microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I want to develop a microservice application in spring boot. I have created 2 services which are called user service and recipe service.

My question is that one user can have multiple recipes but I cannot determine the type of the recipes field. I cannot use `private List<Recipe> recipes` because I want that each microservice should be independent. Do you have any idea?

If I determine like that `private List<Long> recipes` how to do send a request with postman?

```
{
    "id": 102,
    "userName": "figen",
    "email": 3,
    "recipes":5,6,7     // line 5
}
```

this request is not working because of line 5

```java
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

//@Entity
@Document(collection = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String userName;

    private Long email;

    private List<Long> recipes; // I cannot determine this type(one-to-many relationship)

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String id, String userName, Long email,List<Long> recipes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.notes = recipes;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Long getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Long email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Long> getRecipes() {
        return recipes;
    }

    public void setRecipes(List<Long> recipes) {
        this.notes = recipes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", recipes=" + recipes+
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: You may send via postman as  `"intArrayName" : [111,222,333],
  "stringArrayName" : ["a","b","c"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"recipes":5,6,7` will cause an error because recipes have type `List`. You can pass List via postman as following

- For List of 
  `"intArrayName" : [111,222,333]`
- For List of String 
  `"stringArrayName" : ["a","b","c"]`

For above UseCase, you can send it as

```
{
    "id": 102,
    "userName": "figen",
    "email": 3,
    "recipes":[5,6,7]    
}
```

Comment: In mongoDb, it writes No field in notes column.Other columns are working

Comment: Hello @sneijder10. can you please update the question with full error in console

Comment: You have written *I cannot determine this type(one-to-many relationship)*  so have you used @OneToMany relationship or you were talking about List<Long>

Comment: Hello.There is no error actually.I send request with postman.It returns 200 Ok.BUT I can see No field on the table for notes column.

Comment: I am talking about List<Long>.On recipes column I see No field.

Comment: @sneijder10 Please share code where you save the data

Comment: Thank you very much.It is working.Property name was different in postman.

Comment: Welcome @sneijder10

Answer (score 1):

it will work after adding the [] at recipes.

```
{
    "id": 102,
    "userName": "figen",
    "email": 3,
    "recipes":[5,6,7]  
}
```

Comment: In mongoDb, it writes No field in notes column.Other columns are working